Which transitive $G$-sets appear when repeatedly inducing and restricting $G/H$, where $H\subseteq G$ is an inclusion of finite groups?
Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup. Then $G/H$ is a transitive $G$-set. We can define a sequence of $G$-sets as follows:
$$X_0=G/H$$
$$X_{n+1}=Ind_H^GRes^G_HX_n$$
Like every finite $G$-set, $X_n$ is a finite union of transitive $G$-sets, which are all of the form $G/K$ for some subgroup $K$ of $G$. For which subgroups $K$ does $G/K$ appear as a subobject of $X_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
As a first observation, we always have $K\supseteq H^\circ$, where $H^\circ$ denotes the normal core of $H$ in $G$, the largest normal subgroup of $G$ which is contained in $H$.
Hence, we may as well assume $H\subseteq G$ has trivial normal core, since we can replace $G$ with $G/H^\circ$.
On the other hand, since the vectorspace $\mathbb{C}^{G/H}$ of complex valued functions on $G/H$ tensor-generates the category $Rep(G/{H^\circ})\subseteq Rep(G)$ of complex representations where $H^\circ$ acts trivially, I suspect that $G/{H^\circ}$ appears as a subobject for some $n$.
My wild speculation is that $G/K$ will eventually appear whenever $H^\circ\subseteq K\subseteq H$.
For context: in some research, I found myself wanting to know what indecomposable separable algebras in $Rep(G)$ appear as summands of $(Ind_H^GRes^G_H)^n\mathbb{C}^{G/H}$, which is the linear version of this question. I have convinced myself that the functors $S\mapsto\mathbb{C}^S$ from sets with a group action to group representations respect induction and restriction, so I believe the set and linear forms of the question are equivalent.
